# Cocoa equivalent to Java's Reader classes

Tags: java, objective-c, cocoa, io

In porting a Java program to Cocoa, I've come across the program using java.io.Reader and its subclasses. I'm not very familiar with what they do, so I can't find a good replacement. Does anyone have any good recommendations on replacements or do I have to rewrite it?

Comment: Most of us don't know any more about what a java.io.Reader is than you do, which means there's no way we can suggest an equivalent. You should *directly* describe what you want; only then can we recommend something that provides it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to have to dig through the code to find how they use it. I was hoping to change their code as little as possible to avoid bugs, but there's no way around that here.

Comment: @Peter Hosey - a Java has to I/O constructs: Streams and Readers. Streams work with binary data, Readers work with character (unicode and encodings) data. Like NSStrings, all Java characters are UTF-16. With readers it's trivial to, say, open a File, and read 5 "characters", and the Reader does all of the encoding and decoding for you. NSString doesn't give you that, and there doesn't seem to be an equivalent set of library functions in the Apple frameworks.

Comment: @Will Hartung: There is the NSString +stringWithContentsOfFile: method, though that's only distantly related.

Comment: Yea, that doesn't work very well with enormous files. Mac OS is missing the whole concept of the StreamDecoder class. Really frustrating when you're used to what Java gives you for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readers in Java are just "objectified" versions of block file read operations. In Objective C, you have access to the C library. That gives you [fopen, fread, fclose](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/), which are functions for reading raw data files block by block. Isn't that all that's really needed?

Then, if you need to read integers for example, you just cast the (void*) data blocks to (int*).

You could argue that a Java Reader is more abstract. Yes, there are subclasses for reading stuff from anywhere, not just files. But if you're porting an existing program, you already know if the data source is a file or not.

Comment: Java's Reader classes handle the difficulties of working with multi-byte characters. It's not as simple as pulling in a buffer of bytes at a time and then converting them to NSStrings.

Comment: @TroyJ I think NSString has initWithBytes:length:encoding: just for that.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552673 to see how much work is involved just in getting that one method to behave usefully when streaming. Reader also handles the stream unicode prefix to automatically detect the encoding. Reader and subclasses are just a very simple and powerful set of classes. I'm really shocked nothing like it exists even in 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @TroyJ OK, I didn't realize you want to build a string from an incomplete stream. I don't immediately see a use case for that but you're right, it's not easy to do.